# What's wrong with this Jade data binding?

Tags: javascript, binding, pug

What's wrong with this Jade? Thanks.

```
input#a
h1= document.getElementById('a').value
```

The error given is blank.

Comment: `Jade` is a template engine. By the time the `jade` file is rendered, there is no DOM available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Amberlamps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191261/amberlamps) suggests, you have to wait until the DOM is ready.

```
input#a
h1

//- presuming you are using jQuery
script
    $(function() {
        $('h1').html($('input#a').val());
    });
```